# JsonWebTokenHandler ValidateToken throws exception: IDX10503 every alternate attempts

Tags: c#, jwt

I am having below exception:

> IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: '[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'.
> Number of keys in Configuration: '0'.
> Exceptions caught:
> '[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
> token: '[PII of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. See https://aka.ms/IDX10503 for details.

When ValidateToken using JsonWebTokenHandler with the code below:

```
using (var ecdsa = CreateECDsa(VerificationKey))
{
    var publicKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa);
    var decryptKey = CreateDecryptKey();

    var handler = new JsonWebTokenHandler();

    var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = publicKey,
        TokenDecryptionKey = decryptKey
    };

    return await handler.ValidateTokenAsync(token, parameters);
}
```

I am pretty sure key is correct and the token is valid. As exception only happens on every alternate attempts. i.e. the 1st call is ok, but the 2nd will fail and then 3rd will works but 4th one will fail...

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is miss-leading. If you go to the link provided in the exception message: https://aka.ms/IDX10503. It has better explanation on what actually happened.

> IDX10503: Signature validation failed
> This exception message is generated when a token signature cannot be
> verified by any of the provided keys. The described scenario may
> happen if data has been tampered with or if a corresponding key is not
> present.
>
> In some cases, IDX10503: **Signature validation failed error is caused
> by disposing of a cryptographic object** before it is actually used for
> signing or signature validation. One way this can happen is by calling
> a Dispose() method explicitly. Another situation where this can occur
> is when a cryptographic object is created inside of a using block, and
> signing/validation is done outside of the using block.

The root cause is this:

```
using (var ecdsa = CreateECDsa(VerificationKey))
```

as the ecdsa key will be disposed after ValidateToken. This doesn't seem to be an issue at the first glance as you would thought a new key is created for every ValidateToken, the old disposed one is never re-used, how can this be a problem? However, it is, as at somewhere deep down in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, it caches the key and try to re-use it for the next ValidateToken call. Obviously, the 2nd call will fail as the key is already disposed. Then the framework code will remove the key from cache as result of the failing validation. The 3rd ValidateToken call will succeed but it will cache it again.

The solution is to stop the caching and it can be done by

```
var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ....
        CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory
        {
            CacheSignatureProviders = false
        }
    };
```

This can also be done:

```
var publicKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa);
publicKey.CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory
{
    CacheSignatureProviders = false
};
```

You can also turn off the default caching behavior globally:

```
CryptoProviderFactory.DefaultCacheSignatureProviders = false;
```

But this is global setting, so has bigger impact.

Of cause, you can also choose to re-use the key and let the cache to play its role.